# How to split a csv line that has commas for formatting numbers

Tags: python-3.x, csv, parsing

I download a cvs file ussing request and when I need to split but it has some formatting commas in the numbers fields, like:

```
line='2019-07-05,sitename.com,"14,740","14,559","7,792",$11.47'
```

when I try to splits:

```
data = line.split(',')
```

it got this value:

> ['2019-07-05', 'nacion.com', '"14', '740"', '"14', '559"',
>   '"7','792"', '$11.47']

I would need:

> ['2019-07-05', 'nacion.com', '14740', '14559', '7792', '$11.47']

I need to solve it in python 3.7

any help is welcome

Comment: Use Pandas to open the CSV or Use RegEx for more fine parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't like using regex but there may be no other option here. Try this - it basically removes the inside `,`s in two steps:

```
import re

line='2019-07-05,sitename.com,"14,740","14,559","7,792",$11.47'

new_line = re.sub(r',(?!\d)', r"xxx", line).replace(',','').replace('xxx',',')
print(new_line)
```

Output

> 2019-07-05,sitename.com,"14740","14559","7792",$11.47

You can now use:

```
data = new_line.split(',')
```

Explanation:
The regex `,(?!\d)` selects all `,`s in `line` that are not between two digits. The `.sub` replaces those (temporarily) with `xxx`s. The next `.replace` deletes the remaining `,`s which are inside numbers by replacing them with nothing and, finally, the last `.replace` restores the `,` delimiters by replacing the temporary `xxx`s with `,`.